# Cannot create azure ad application with oauth via terraform

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Im trying to create/register application in Azure AD with oauth2_permissions / scopes.
Im following this documentatino page to do so: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/r/application.html
And I have reduced it to that simple .tf file:

```
provider "azuread" {
  version = "=0.7.0"
  subscription_id = "*******************************"
  tenant_id = var.tenant-id
}

resource "azuread_application" "example" {
  name = "example"
//  oauth2_permissions {
//    admin_consent_description = "Allow the application to access example on behalf of the signed-in user."
//    admin_consent_display_name = "Access example"
//    is_enabled = true
//    type = "User"
//    user_consent_description = "Allow the application to access example on your behalf."
//    user_consent_display_name = "Access example"
//    value = "user_impersonation"
//  }
}
```

Running script like this with `terraform plan` says:

> C:\source\ITAN\terraform (master -> origin) λ terraform plan
> Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan... The refreshed
> state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be persisted
> to local or remote state storage.
>
> ---
>
> An execution plan has been generated and is shown below. Resource
> actions are indicated with the following symbols:   + create
>
> Terraform will perform the following actions:
>
> azuread_application.example will be created   + resource
> azuread_application" "example" {
>
> ```
>   + application_id  = (known after apply)
>   + homepage        = (known after apply)
>   + id              = (known after apply)
>   + identifier_uris = (known after apply)
>   + name            = "example"
>   + object_id       = (known after apply)
>   + owners          = (known after apply)
>   + public_client   = (known after apply)
>   + reply_urls      = (known after apply)
>   + type            = "webapp/api"
>
>   + oauth2_permissions {
>       + admin_consent_description  = (known after apply)
>       + admin_consent_display_name = (known after apply)
>       + id                         = (known after apply)
>       + is_enabled                 = (known after apply)
>       + type                       = (known after apply)
>       + user_consent_description   = (known after apply)
>       + user_consent_display_name  = (known after apply)
>       + value                      = (known after apply)
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
>
> ---
>
> Note: You didn't specify an "-out" parameter to save this plan, so
> Terraform can't guarantee that exactly these actions will be performed
> if "terraform apply" is subsequently run.

But when I uncomment the `oauth2_permissions`

```
provider "azuread" {
  version = "=0.7.0"
  subscription_id = "******************"
  tenant_id = var.tenant-id
}

resource "azuread_application" "example" {
  name = "example"
  oauth2_permissions {
    admin_consent_description = "Allow the application to access example on behalf of the signed-in user."
    admin_consent_display_name = "Access example"
    is_enabled = true
    type = "User"
    user_consent_description = "Allow the application to access example on your behalf."
    user_consent_display_name = "Access example"
    value = "user_impersonation"
  }
}
```

Problem occurs and it states like this:

> Error: "oauth2_permissions.0.user_consent_display_name": this field
> cannot be set
>
> on itan-azure-ad.tf line 7, in resource "azuread_application"
> "example":    7: resource "azuread_application" "example" {

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Im logged in, I have selected proper subscription and switched to it. I own the azure account. I have created application via azure portal successully, yet I want to have it done automatically. Running on terraform:

```
terraform -v
Terraform v0.12.28
+ provider.azuread v0.7.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not supported to set `user_consent_display_name` in the version `provider.azuread v0.7.0`. See `oauth2_permissions` in the change log [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azuread/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Please use the latest azuread provider version 0.11.0. It will fix your issue.

```
provider "azuread" {
  version = "~>0.11.0"
  subscription_id = "*******************************"
  tenant_id = var.tenant-id
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I used 0.7.0 from this https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/index.html
Where to find plugin/provider versions?

Comment: @jstadnicki Glad to know my answer is helpful. The sample provided in the link you shared is outdated. As I mentioned in my answer, you can see the change log [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azuread/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). If you want to see the changes in the history `azuread` application files, see https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azuread/commits/master/azuread/resource_application.go.

Comment: Understand, once again thanks. Will update my remaining providers then.